# Row vector with equal spacing

Tags: spacing, vector

[image]

In this MWE the alignment of the last element in the tuple is not nice.
How can I get the spacing for the last element at the same size as the others? The description "n+1" may overlap the comma from the first line.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{*{21}{c}}
\Bigl( &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &\Bigr) \;. \\
    & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \uparrow & \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & n+1 &
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest trick is to put `n+1` in a box of zero width:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{*{21}{c}}
\Bigl( &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &\Bigr) \;. \\
    & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \uparrow & \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \makebox[0pt]{$n+1$} &
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

A better solution is to employ the package `mathtools` (an extension of `amsmath`) which provides the macro `\mathclap` with the same effect but refined, since it will choose the correct math style (irrelevant in this case but important in other situations).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{mathtools}% loads amsmath

\begin{document}

Without correction:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{*{21}{c}}
\Bigl( &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &\Bigr) \;. \\
    & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \uparrow & \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & n+1 &
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

With \verb+\mathclap+
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{*{21}{c}}
\Bigl( &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &, &* &\Bigr) \;. \\
    & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & & 0 & \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \uparrow & \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \mathclap{n+1} &
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds.  Well done.

Comment: Thx. Great minds think alike `;-)`